# recaptcha 2 width css float not work

Tags: css, recaptcha

I work with recaptcha version 2.0 and need to resize width like this:

CSS:

```
.g-recaptcha {
    float:right;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.77);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.77);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.77);
    -o-transform: scale(0.77);
    transform: scale(0.77);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

this worked but when I need to set `float:right` for show `recaptcha` in right, I see blank space!! how do fix this ??

problem: [image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eLvoe3cu/

Comment: add complete code to `Jsfiddle`

Comment: @Abdulla: http://jsfiddle.net/eLvoe3cu/

Answer (score 0):

Try this(Define `padding-right`)

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="padding-right: 0px"> //here
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group"  style="padding-right: 0px">//here
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="normal" data-sitekey="6LdWTgkTAAAAAGKrAUJV55zGhVhik0J2T5hnHtgO"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary post-comments">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group"></div>
</div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Comment: @Perspolis try with `padding:0px`